# SFTP via JSch is throwing error 4: Failure

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, winscp

I am facing a peculiar issue while trying to SFTP a file from Windows to Unix server. The error "stack trace" is -

```
4: Failure
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.checkStatus(ChannelSftp.java:2459)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._sendCLOSE(ChannelSftp.java:2465)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:683)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:475)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:365)
```

I have searched a lot on other forums but could not get to the root cause. I have observed one more thing - the file name, I am trying to SFTP, is *.xml when I change it to *.XML the SFTP is "successful". Very weird could not identify the issue. I am trying this using JSch Java API. But I have seen the same issue while trying the WinSCP front end.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is [common for OpenSSH SFTP server to return code 4 (Failure) for many different reasons, without giving any details](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/sftp_codes#code_4).

You would have to check [SFTP server log](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Logging_and_Troubleshooting) to find more.

Though the most usual cause is a lack of free disk or user quota space – Which can usually be identified by the file being created with zero size.

Comment: In my case, the destination path was invalid: `channelSftp.put(new ByteArrayInputStream("Hello World!".getBytes()),"/Bad/path/hello.txt");`

Answer (score 4):

i was facing the same issue. was puzzled then i realized there was a space issue on the server folder. Please do check the server available space.

command:  df path to the folder

Comment: Same with me, it was a space issue problem

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. Please make sure that your SFTP service is running. And If it is already running then restarting this service should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Tried everything, turns out I had set the timeout to what I thought was 30s but it was actually 30ms. Changing it to 30000ms solved the issue.

```
session.setTimeout(30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error and the cause in my case was, the uploaded file names weren't supported by the file system used by the SFTP server.